# Debug Connectivity Issue in gRPC Dial

Tags: go, grpc

I'm trying to make a gRPC connection to a server. In my client code (go version: go1.13 darwin/amd64), I have

```
conn, err = grpc.DialContext(ctx, c.tiProxyURL, grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock(), grpc.WithBackoffMaxDelay(10*time.Second))
```

This blocks the code as the connection is for some reason not established. Is there any way to debug this further and figure out what is the issue with the connection?

The connection is established when I'm running the server code on my local machine, but is blocked when trying to connect to a service deployed in the cloud through the ingress URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you could reproduce locally & use IDE, I think break point could help you.

But if not, I would recommend:

1. Try to add timeout to the context to avoid it blocking forever
2. Use `InsecureSkipVerify` in TLS config. On my case, it hangs due to disabling transport security on a secure transport layer.

**Example:**

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*5)
defer cancel()
config := &tls.Config{
  InsecureSkipVerify: true,
}
tlsCredential := credentials.NewTLS(config)
conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, c.tiProxyURL, tlsCredential, grpc.WithBlock(), grpc.WithBackoffMaxDelay(10*time.Second))
```

**Note:**
Setting `InsecureSkipVerify` as true, comes with security risk. Recommended only for debugging purpose or on a trusty network only.

**Reference:**

```
    // InsecureSkipVerify controls whether a client verifies the server's
    // certificate chain and host name. If InsecureSkipVerify is true, crypto/tls
    // accepts any certificate presented by the server and any host name in that
    // certificate. In this mode, TLS is susceptible to machine-in-the-middle
    // attacks unless custom verification is used. This should be used only for
    // testing or in combination with VerifyConnection or VerifyPeerCertificate.
    InsecureSkipVerify bool
```